# What would the effects of a muscle-wrapped mesh of a circulatory system be on a human?

Tags: biology, anatomy, bio-mechanics, blood, body-modification

Let's say that there is a biomodified human. Their circulatory system is something of a mesh; there are artificial connections between their blood vessels wherever physically possible, generally at intervals of ~0.1 millimeters.

Moreover, tiny artificial muscles have grown around every blood vessel in their body; they assist the heart in pumping blood by giving it a "boost", and function in a similar fashion to [peristalsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristalsis).

These artificial capillaries are capable of distinguishing between oxygenated and deoxygenated blood.

How would this different configuration of circulatory system effect a human? I personally am of the impression that it would help somewhat with the following three health issues, but I'm well-aware that there are probably more:

- stopping bodily tissues from dying of blood loss or swelling-induced necrosis; after all, it's much harder for a part of the body to die of oxygen loss when there are multiple blood vessels delivering blood to the same area
- stopping blood clots from effecting the body; after all, when one vein gets clogged, there are still three more pumping blood around the blockage
- stopping blood loss from severe bodily harm; the mini-muscles around each blood vessel can pinch them off in the event that they're severed

Comment: "it's much harder to cause blood loss when there are multiple blood vessels delivering blood to the same area" - I'm not sure I get your reasoning, why wouldn't it have the exact opposite effect. Also, I'm not really clear in what ways this differs from the circulation that we already have - except the peristalsis thing (arterial walls are already smooth-muscles).

Comment: @ARogueAnt. For the first bit: sorry, I meant something else. For the second bit: I mean that each blood vessel is connected to each and every adjacent blood vessel at ~0.1mm intervals. I will edit to clarify both of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They'd rely less on their heart for circulation I'd imagine, to the point of being a little resistant to the usually lethal sentence that is a heart attack but all of these muscles contracting near constantly will undoubtedly make them feel a little... undulate-y. Imagine feeling your heartbeat across your entire body. Unless you get used to it you're most likely going to go a little mad.

"Do you feel it? ... **the thumping!**"

This kind of thing may also lead to a higher blood pressure with all the health issues that entails.

Comment: They can just put themselves on a low-sodium diet, then, as well as anti-anxiety meds. +1.